# How to cache the video on the browser and used the cached version every time the video is played

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]i am using a video on my website. The problem is the video gets downloaded every time it is loaded. For eg. When the video loads for the first time the browser downloads the 5.3 mb of video. Since i am using html 5 video loop and autoplay, it loops and again downloads another 5.3mb of video. This happens every time the video is loaded.
Is there any trick to cache the video for once and used the cached version as long as the video is played.

Comment: Which browser are you in, and do you have the Dev tools open?

Comment: I am using Chrome Canary. The dev tools is open.

Comment: I can't find the link right now, but that is normal behaviour from Chrome Dev tools. It will show it loading each time it loops to help you out when debugging etc. For your site visitors, who obviously don't have dev tools open, it will be caching properly. This threw me once as well. Apologies I can't find the link/resource that explains it. EDIT: I think there is a 'disable cache while dev tools open' option somewhere in chrome

Comment: The problem is it is not caching. Every time it downloads the video when it is looped. If we keep the website open for too long..it is downloading 100s of mb of data from that video. It was costing us too much...so as of now i have made the video to play it once and stop. any solution to that?

Comment: It will cache if you don't have dev tools open. You can also change the option I referred to above if you want it to cache whilst you have dev tools open. It will be caching fine for anyone else that it visiting the website.

Comment: If you are referring to DevTools Settings "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)", it is unchecked. Apologies if I am getting you wrong.

Comment: If you are referring to DevTools Settings "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)", it is unchecked. Apologies if I am getting you wrong. I have added screenshot for the reference. Is that behavior normal?

Comment: You can see from your screenshot that it is loading from cache. (from cache) is in the size column for all the requests

Comment: I am relying on the browser to get cached.

Comment: @swapnilshah you're video **IS** cached. you can see at the bottom of Chrome `0B transfered`...

Answer (score 3):

Answered for anyone else that comes across this question.

Chrome has an option to disable the cache while devtools is open. This is set as default to unchecked, i.e normal behaviour.

If you look at the screenshot in the question, you can see in the size column "(from cache)" that although it looks like Chrome is re-downloading the video each time, it is actually getting it from the cache.

Comment: yes true. Is there any way we stop the re-downloading? thanks.

Comment: @swapnilshah go have a look at your server transfer logs, you will see it is **NOT** downloading multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Pogrindis and OliverM. This was very helpful