# Why video is not been cached on browser?

Tags: reactjs, caching, video, browser

I read a lot of question about this problem but unfortunately, this is the most near to my problem [Video cache problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407051/how-to-cache-the-video-on-the-browser-and-used-the-cached-version-every-time-the)

[image]

In the screenshot, you can see how the main_home.mp4 file is downloaded multiples times, and never from the cache, my video has 87Mb, last night with the page open I downloaded more than 10GB.

Comment: Did you enable caching in Developer Tools as suggested? Does your server logs say there's multiple downloads even when you don't open Dev Tools? How is the video data served, for example are you using a PHP script or using MP4 in video tag `src`? Is caching disabled on your server somehow? If still unsolved... Can you provide a test link to one video file?

Comment: Hi, @VC.One I just optimize my videos I got smaller video size, converting the videos to WebM format. now is caching and working as expected.